# Can we implement SOA style in MVC architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, soa

Is to possible to have a layout for web-based architecture based on MVC where SOA is the architectural style. Or to rephrase, can services be part of the M,V, C of MVC.If so, what kinds of services can be included in each of them. Also, can you give me a real world example?

Answer (score 7):

In a SOA application you are typically not including the front end (presentation layer). You are consuming those services in your MVC application, or better yet in a separate "model" project that the MVC application uses.

Data Access -> Business Logic -> Services -> Models -> MVC

The point is to use the services to create an abstraction around the base of your application to allow for multiple clients to consume those services.

Comment: I like your answer, but am a bit confused by having *two* models -- the *model* in MVC *plus* the one you mention.  Is there a reason MVC shouldn't talk directly to the services (either in the model or the controller)?

Comment: @Kirk, no there is not. However, I find it nicer to abstract the services in the models. Then I can also create my own view models, which is often necessary as the models to not line up to the views 100%.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to term the Model as represented in the client/presentation layer as the ViewModel, it is simply the presentation layers view of the model. Not the actual Domain model.This is needed in a SOA as the context of the consumer of the Model changes often

In SOA`s we try to get to a canonical schema for the contract, as it is quite likely that not all clients now and in the future will require the exact same view of the model.

Thus be it a web client, service client or a desktop client, if you think of the Model in MVC as the ViewModel, this allows you to abstract presentation layer things away from Service layer things, and you get closer to a canonical schema.

So an example View >> Controller >> ViewModel(Model) >> Data Contract >> Service

Examples of how to build a service stack like this can be found here:

[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

The decision of whether to go with a REST architecture or a full WS-* SOAP is a separate concern and should not affect your choice of MVC as a presentation pattern.

There may of course be other constraints that preclude the use of one or the other.

Choosing a presentation pattern for a new or enterprise web development on the Microsoft platform is a daunting task, in my opinion there are only three; View Model, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) or ASP.NET MVC (a Model2 derivative).

You can read the full article here [ASP.NET MVC Patterns](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you mean by SOA. If you are referring to WS-* standards, I would not recommend MVC, as you will need to write a lot of plumbing to get it to work.

If you are looking for something like a REST service, then the MVC pattern actually works quite well. The request is the HTTP location of the resource, which gets passed to the controller, which loads the data via the model, and then passes it to the view which returns it in whatever form is needed (JSON, XML, Binary, etc). Or, you can often return the result directly, depending on what framework you use.

Erick

Comment: If we consider the e-voting system, I have implemented them as registration service, authentication service, voting service,etc,...If I have to use MVC, I probably would have reorganize these services so that they fit in the model view and controller of MVC. Also for these services to interact , I could use REST technology. Is this the way it works?

Comment: I have to disagree. A true service oriented application is quite possible with MVC and with any other framework on any platform. That is the point of SOA. MVC does not have anything to do with it, the front end should just consume the services.

Comment: @Dustin, I do agree that MCV can fit with SOA, for a given value of SOA. I hope my post didn't imply otherwise! My main point was that SOA often includes the WS-* stuff, which is very difficult to work with when using MVC. I am referring to common MVC technologies, not the MVC pattern in general, as that would open up a whole new can of worms.