# What are the advantages of using a traditional MVC framework Vs Using an HTML + Javascript + Services application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, web-applications, architecture

Im right now architecting a Web application and the customer is not sure about using ASP.NET MVC or any other MVC Framework (Rails, Djando or other apply also).

The customer doesnt see value in using these frameworks.  They prefer to use traditional HTML and call Web Services via JavaScript to get all the data.  For them SOA is very important and they want all the application to be SOA oriented.  In the current development, we are returning some data to the views for the initial loading of the home page(using an ORM tool and doint all calculations in the controllers and returning the model to the view), and any updates to the page are executed calling Rest Services using JavaScript.  The customer is complaining about returning data to the views using the controllers.  They want all data to be returned via the web services, so the MVC framework for them is useless.  What can i say to the customer to "sell" the use of the MVC framework?

What are the Pros and Cons of using each architecture?

Thanks

Comment: You can still have SOA, just call services from MVC controllers, and from the client where appropriate. I prefer using MVC if there is business logic that needs to be implemented which shouldn't be exposed on the client. If the product they have lends itself to being "one page app" then it makes sense to just use that one page and services for the data retrieval/saving.

Comment: The idea behind the MVC framework it's to help you to create bigger and faster and organized web applications which in my opinion it's something that the customer have to see because it's could do more in less time which converts in less costs.

Comment: You can still use MVC with a complete SOA backend. Essentially, you're just removing the 'M' from MVC. There's still value in the separation of concerns you get from MVC, and it's also *much* more flexible that a 100% JavaScript SPA. 100% JavaScript is hard to do *right*; it takes exponentially more man-hours, and is more expensive to produce as a result. If you're not charging for the labor-intensity of this approach, you should be. Besides, there's still these things called screen readers out there that everyone forgets about. They don't handle JS-only sites well.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net MVC, you can make use of a service-oriented architecture and continue using MVC for the back end, the front end will meet your html, javascript to use (front-controller) and use SOA to connect to your back end for message passing (JSON) in your back end can have a MVC architecture to manage your services

Answer (score 1):

It all depends....

You can, of course, [use the MVC pattern from within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework). You can also [hook an MVC application into a service-oriented architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110898/can-we-implement-soa-style-in-mvc-architecture).

I think the question comes down to "where do you construct the page" - front end, or server-side.

The benefits of constructing the page in the browser are obvious. You can scale more easily, because a lot of heavy lifting happens in the client. You are forced to create loosely coupled services, which you can compose in lots of interesting ways.

The drawbacks are perhaps a little subtler. Most search engines won't execute the JavaScript, so the HTML rendered by your services may well be invisible to them. As the number of browsers increases (smart phones, smart TV, etc.), testing this kind of application logic can become overwhelming. Practically, there may well be a limit to the amount of business and application logic you want to put into JavaScript - download time and execution time can become a problem, and it requires a lot of discipline from the development team. Depending on the page logic, you may not be able to cache quite as much as when constructing pages on the server.

Benefits of server-side page construction are also fairly obvious: you can take advantage of well-established libraries and frameworks. Your pages can be cached on the browser or CDN. By testing the business and/or application logic on the server, you can be confident it will work on all devices (though the user interface may well break). It's probably easier to expose server-generated pages in different formats when constructing them on the server (e.g. HTML and RSS versions).

Drawbacks of server-side page generation include not easily being able to pull apart different components and re-use them unless you design that in from the start. Where a web application depends on lots of services, the back-end code may not earn its keep.